# Can you create custom shortcuts in ChromeOS, including the specific URL and icon, without developer accounts?

Tags: url, shortcut, favicon, google-chrome-os, chromebook

ChromeOS has the option to create a shortcut from the site you are currently have open in a given window/tab. However this has a few problems:

1. The icon cannot be customized

   - If the "favorite" icon provided by the site is low quality or not true to the product's brand, you can't change; also in many cases (like a specific Google doc) it's too generic.
2. The URL is changed under some cases

   - If you have multiple profiles logged in, and you select a secondary account, Google use the URL pattern /u/1 .. N for the profile you selected; however this is stripped if you're creating a shortcut, and you'll get only the base URL in the shortcut.